# Табличная верстка DIVами

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Предположим, есть таблица такого плана:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><img src=""></td><td>some text</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src=""></td><td>some text</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src=""></td><td>some text</td></tr>
</table>
```

Колонки таблицы по 50%, высота строк - одинакова. Картинки в первом столбце разных размеров, но все должны быть выровнены по центру первой ячейки. Текст в правом столбце должен быть выровнен по правому краю и центрирован по вертикали.

Как это реализовать в табличной верстке, - я знаю. А вот как реализовать это с помощью только div и css? (Пример.)

Comment: Табличная верстка div'ами! Гениально!

Comment: Реализовать-то можно все, **НО ЗАЧЕМ**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения моей задачи использовались установка свойства `line-height` для родительского контейнера и набор свойств `{ display: inline-block; line-height: 1.1; vertical-align: middle; }` для вложенных элементов, которые необходимо выровнять по вертикали, горизонтальное выравнивание - простым `{ text-align:center; }`

Это html:

```
    <div class="block-core">
        <div class="left-image"><img src="b1.png"></div>
        <div class="right-text"><p>Seat Pre-Booking App 18%</p></div>
    </div>
```

и цсс к нему:

```
.left-image {
position:relative;
float:left;
width:200px;
height:70px;
line-height:70px;
text-align:center;
}
.left-image img {
display: inline-block;
line-height: 1.1;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.right-text {
position:relative;
float:right;
width:200px;
height:70px;
line-height:70px;
}
.right-text p {
font-size:11pt;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 1.1;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Стандартная html-таблица может быть воспроизведена дивами с такими классами:

```
.table     { display: table }
.tr        { display: table-row }
.thead     { display: table-header-group }
.tbody     { display: table-row-group }
.tfoot     { display: table-footer-group }
.col       { display: table-column }
.colgroup  { display: table-column-group }
.td, .th    { display: table-cell }
.caption   { display: table-caption }
```

Answer (score -2):

Грубо говоря так:

```
  <style>
    .td {
        background-color: wheat;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .break{
        clear: both;
    }
    </style>
    <div id="main_container">
    <div class="td">1</div><div class="td">2</div>
    <div class="break"></div>
    <div class="td">3</div><div class="td">4</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: а картинки, выровненные по центру первой "колонки" где?.. вертикальное выравнивание в ячейках второй колонки - где?..

Comment: Правильно, @deivan, так его! ))) Не хотят работать нормально. Еще и тринадцатой зарплаты лишить. Ужос, какой-то!

Comment: Очень грубо говоря)

Comment: цитирую ТС

>МОИ ПРЕИМУЩЕСТВА:
>
>не боюсь сложных задач, это они боятся меня
>довожу начатое до конца и не даю несбыточных обещаний
>готов экстренно и успешно переучиться на любую новую технологию, >быстро дать нужный результат
>работу выполняю с удовольствием, как для себя, отношусь к своим >проектам как к родным детям
>говорю то, что думаю (хотя некоторые считают это недостатком)
>

Comment: ["а компот ?" :))))][1]


  [1]: http://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%C2%AB%D0%AB%C2%BB_%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A8%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: руки... мыли?

Comment: с мылом, мыли.
Давай компот!

Comment: я уже нашел свое решение, но хочу посмотреть, есть ли варианты красивее. век живи - век учись.

Comment: ну так похвастайтесь же уже наконец! а мы поправим)

Comment: хотелось хотя бы еще один реальный вариант увидеть. моя задача - весьма конкретна, в ней две трудности - поставить картинку по центру ячейки и поставить текст с вертикальным выравниванием, аналогично табличным параметрам align=\"center\" и valign=\"middle\". что-то тут скучновато становится..

Comment: @deivan, а картинки и выравнивание я оставил для развития творческого потенциала вопрошающего, иначе вопрос можно закрыть как "Работа за автора" :)